# Access to resources from an unapproved, external host violates the Content Security Policy (CSP)

Tags: visualforce, experience-cloud, csp

I'm facing the following error:

[image]

**What I'm trying to do:**

- I have a Visualforce page hosted on an Aura Component (using iFrame).
- Everything works fine in the Salesforce Org.
- However, I tried to access the same component from the Experience Site. This error keeps popping up.
- Along with this error, the browser console shows some errors too:
  [image]

**What I've tried to fix this:**

- Added URLs to CSP from setup.
- Added URLs to remote site setting.
- Added URLs to Experience Builder Security Setting like below, still no luck!

Beside these, the main issue I'm facing is:
**The static resources aren't loaded. That's why the design is broke.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that the URL is not in [canonical form](https://moz.com/learn/seo/canonicalization). That means if you have a URL such as:

```
//apex/myPage
```

The browser may interpret it as:

```
https://apex/myPage
```

Similarly, `undefined` means that you never set a variable's value, or you may have made a typo in the code somewhere. You'll need to fix that, too.

Comment: But, everything is working fine in the Salesforce Org. Mainly static resources aren't loading in the Experience Site. The design is broke. If there was typo, wouldn't there be issue in the org too?

Comment: @Mehedi I'm also working on an app that runs both in a LWR DE and Salesforce, and there are things that just don't work quite the same. Unfortunately, there's not enough detail here to tell you exactly what's wrong. You'll need to do some sleuthing. Open your DE with the F12 Developer Console open, and in the Sources tab, set "Break on exceptions" and "Break on caught exceptions". You can probably find out where things are breaking from there.

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, I've tweaked several stuffs. Now facing a issue: 'This content is blocked. Contact the site owner to fix the issue.' Check this image: https://ibb.co/jGPwHKJ  
So, currently all are loading except the VF page.(VF is hosted on Aura). Could you please share what to troubleshoot?

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, the following error shows on the Experience Site: https://ibb.co/QY08y9S 
Could you please check?